# Will LOCK TABLES unlock a previous LOCK IN SHARE MODE

Tags: mysql, transactions

The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html) says that

> LOCK TABLES is not transaction-safe and implicitly commits any active transaction before attempting to lock the tables.

Does this mean that `LOCK TABLES` will cause the unlocking of rows in a previous `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE` statement within the same transaction?

If yes, then I understand why my online store charges double/triple on some occasions during high traffic load :p